# how to loop adding new column to pandas dataframe with value is based on other column value

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Please I have dataframe with four columns that are [keys, summary, description, and summary_description], so iam dealing with summary_description, trying to apply RegEx and extract the new result in a [New_column], so I have done the looping but Iam not sure what is the problem not working getting error. Please if anyone could help, I would really appreciate it.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
dataf= pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\malotaibi\Desktop\Last update\result.xlsx')
dataf
dataf.head(5)
dataf['New_Column'][i] = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', dataf['Summary_Description'][i])
print (dataf['New_column'][i])
```

Error:

```
KeyError: 'New_Column'
```

Comment: You should do `print(dataf.columns)`, it'll show you the columns you have access to. It says there is no column `New_Column` with a capital C. Check it again.

Comment: iam not sure if my loop is correct ot not, but I did what you said print(dataf.columns), is still the same problem, iam using jupyter. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
dataf['New_Column'] = dataf['Summary_Description'].str.replace('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have tried to add to the 'New Column' key before creating it. So do

```
import pandas as pd
import re
dataf= pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\malotaibi\Desktop\Last update\result.xlsx')
dataf
dataf.head(5)
dataf['New_Column'] = 1 # this will create the new_column entry and set all its values to 1
```

You can now loop through this and set each value to what you want. I assume you're going for something like:

```
for i in range(len(dataf['Summary_Description'])):
    dataf['New_Column'][i] = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', dataf['Summary_Description'][i])
```

Comment: Thank you so much Kathy for your time, it really helped.

Comment: No worries, though I'd like to point out the answer below given by PraveenB is much cleaner and also works, but its up to you